# How to get Php multidimensional array same key’s same value’s related total in new array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

- Php multidimensional array same key’s same value’s related total in
        new array. I have an array of following mentioned. i need new array
        as total qty of same item_id. anyone can help would be appreciate.
        My Original Array is as following

---

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 1
        )
        [qty] => 0
    ),
    [b] => Array
        (
            [item] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 2
            )
            [qty] => 35
    ),
    [c] => Array
    (
            [item] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 2
            ) 
           [qty] => 15
    ),
    [e] => Array
    (
            [item] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 3
            ) 
            [qty] => 20
    ),

);
```

- I want array Output like following :

  ```
  Array(
        [0] => Array (
                [item_id] => 1,   
                [item_total_qty] => 0,    
              )

        [1] => Array (
               [item_id] => 2,    
               [item_total_qty] => 50,    
              )
       [2] => Array (
              [item_id] => 3, 
              [item_total_qty] => 20, 
              )
   );
  ```

Comment: I think you should use recursive function for solution

Comment: ok i am trying that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it help

```
$arrays = array(
    'a' => array(
        'item' => array(
            'item_id' => 1
        ),
        'qty' => 0
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'item' => array(
            'item_id' => 2
        ),
        'qty' => 35
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'item' => array(
            'item_id' => 2
        ),
        'qty' => 15
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'item' => array(
            'item_id' => 3
        ),
        'qty' => 20
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach ($arrays as $key => $array) {
    if (is_array($result) && !empty($result)) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $r) {
            if ($r['item_id'] ==   $array['item']['item_id']) {
                $result[$key]['item_total_qty'] += $array['qty'];
                 continue 2;
            }

        }

        $result[] = array(
                    'item_id' => $array['item']['item_id'],
                    'item_total_qty' => $array['qty']);

    } else {
        $result[] = array(
                    'item_id' => $array['item']['item_id'],
                    'item_total_qty' => $array['qty']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple foreach on your original table:

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ($original as $item) {
    $id = $item['item']['item_id'];
    $sorted[$id]['item_total_qty'] = $sorted[$id] ? $sorted[$id] + $item['qty'] : item['qty'];
    $sorted[$id]['item_id'] = $id;
}
$sorted = array_values($sorted);
```

Comment: i want sum of total qty item_id wise.. this array will only give item_id and qty.

Comment: Sorry, I ommited that You wanted to sum it. I've edited my answer. It seems to work as You want now.